# Failed to add directory 'ros/robo/visual': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists

Tags: svn

**Note: *I have already seen that there are several questions with the same problem but none of them came out to be useful for my purpose (may be because i am new and not able to understand the answers*)**

There are several students who are working for a same folder (having several sub folders and files) and keep adding the files into the SVN managed by the University's department. I have had the updated version of that folder. **Later on, i made some changes into the sub folder `"visual"`** but i did not want to put my changes into the SVN as those were not successful.

Now, after several months, i am trying to update my SVN but i am getting the following error:

`Failed to add directory 'ros/robo/visual': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists`

**What i need now:** I just want to get the updated version of SVN folder even if it deletes my local version (because i don't need my local version anymore). But the most important thing is that, any act of mine should not make any changes in the original repository which is maintained by university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `visual` out of the way, and run `svn up ros/robo`.  If that doesn't work, add the force switch:

```
svn up --force ros/robo
```

That directory might have been scheduled for addition already.  More information might be provided by

```
svn info ros/
```